# Google Form-Triggered Script Only Formatting Top Row of Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-api

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/166qWsdzrT0aG-swARyTC5_qN0NmzQzai1GlxQe1WKHc/edit#gid=305801986) is my project

I have a simple google form for teacher observations, and I want to format the cells with word wrap using a script triggered by each form submission.

```
function triggerWrap() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
var r = s.getDataRange();
r.setWrap(true)
}

function myFunction(e) {

e.range.setWrap(true);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange('B1:O300');
cell.setWrap(true)

var Time = e.values[2];
var TeacherName = e.values[1];
var Date = e.values[3];
var Goal1 = e.values[4];
var Goal1Domains = e.values[5];
var Goal1Teacher = e.values[6];
var Goal1Student = e.values[7];
var Goal1Suggestions = e.values[8];
var Goal2 = e.values[9]; 
var Goal2Domains = e.values[10];
var Goal2Teacher = e.values[11];
var Goal2Student = e.values[12]; 
var Goal2Suggestions = e.values[13]; 
var subject = "Informal Observation Notes for your Records"; 
var message = "Hello,\n" + "Here are the notes from our informal observation:" + "\n\nDate: " + Date + "\n\nTime: " + Time + "\n\nGoal 1:  " + Goal1 + "\n\nDomain(s): " + Goal1Domains + "\n\nObserved Teacher Behaviors:  " + Goal1Teacher + "\n\nObserved Student Behaviors: " + Goal1Student + "\n\nSuggestions: " + Goal1Suggestions;

MailApp.sendEmail (<******>, subject, message);

}
```

As you can see, I've tried a few ways of doing this (once as a separate function and two different ways in my email notification function), but only the top row is getting formatted. I've tried moving the gray line up and down, to no effect.

The strangest part: if you click any of the cells and go to manually format them, it says that it's already set to word wrap. I've also tried setting all cells to overflow and then running the script again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The sheet is set to view only. Also please put any relevant code in the post. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! My mistake. Here is an edit link, and I'll pull the relevant code from the script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/166qWsdzrT0aG-swARyTC5_qN0NmzQzai1GlxQe1WKHc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things. You need to change your function name to onFormSubmit. Also, set up an installable onChange trigger through Resources. In your test data, you need to add a space to you text in each cell. This is a known issue (Issue 6016). I also suggest you add vertical alignment top to your code. Try this:

```
 function onFormSubmit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
   var r = s.getDataRange();
 r.setWrap(true).setVerticalAlignment("top")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The space issue actually just occurred to me a minute ago. I removed the trigger during testing, but it's back now. I'm adding your code as well.